# magical record complex predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I am using MagicalRecord with core data.

The objects I am dealing with are:

salesPerson

salesTool - this has a one to many relationship to salesPerson, but also has a season property.  Each season(spring, summer etc) has a value of either 0 or 1.

I am filling a tableView with my view.  The view has a salesPerson property(self.company).  I would like to call the appropriate seasonal salesTools for the salesPerson.  The Predicate I have tried is--

```
NSPredicate *salesToolFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((salesPerson == %@) AND (spring == '0')), self.salesPerson];
NSArray *salesTools = [salesTool MR_findAllWithPredicate:salesToolFilter];
[_dataArray addObjectsFromArray:salesTools];
```

Unfortunately, this predicate throws an error. 'Unable to parse the format string'  I'm sure this is a simple thing I am doing wrong, but I have yet to figure it out after a couple days and much searching.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outer paraens, and you're missing a trailing ". Prett sure the compiler will catch that for you.  When you get an error like that, look at everything between the quotes, and make sure your expression names

- exist
- are following the proper key paths
- are capitolized correctly
- use the proper format placeholders, like %K, etc

You can also reference the predicate (once it parses) and print it out in the debug console to see how it evaluated (interpreted) by the parser.  However, it seems you aren't that far yet.